# Animate custom views of UITableView Section Headers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app I have a `UITableView` inside a Scene which changes widths dynamically. When the width changes, I animate the expansion of the scene - including the `UITableView`.

The `UITableView` contains section headers with custom views, which contain a `UILabel` which is anchored to the right side of the view.

When the width of my scene changes, I animate the resize of the table like so:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.22
                      delay:0.02
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^
 {
     //Change width to 320 from 220
     [menuTable setFrame:CGRectMake(menuTable.frame.origin.x, menuTable.frame.origin.y, 320, menuTable.frame.size.height)];
 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished)
 {

 }];
```

This smoothly animates the resize of the table, but the label inside the section header pops to the final destination - it does not animate.

I've tried calling `reloadData` - this has the same effect, no animation. I tried calling `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` but it has no effect.

What else should I try?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: UILabel's don't animate text changes. if you set a background color for your label you should see the labels frame animate properly, while the text waits then jumps into place. You'll need a subclass of UILabel to take full control over how the text animates into place.

Comment: @rdelmar - I am using autolayout.

Comment: @RyanPoolos - If I set a background color on the label as you said, I can see that it definitely just pops into place - the label itself isn't animating in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experiments with label expansion, I found that what Ryan Poolos said in his comment is true -- even if the label expands with an animation, the text will jump to its new position (I've done this with the text set to center justification).

So, the only way I've found that works is to use a timer, like so:

```
-(IBAction)expandLabel:(id)sender {

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(expand:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)expand:(NSTimer *) aTimer {
    self.widthCon.constant += 1;
    if (self.widthCon.constant >= 200) [aTimer invalidate];
}
```

widthCon is an IBOutlet to the width constraint I put on the label. If you're using auto layout, you should do any animations by changing the constraints, rather than changing the frame. I haven't tried this with a label in a section header, but I assume it will work if you animate the table's width using this method, and the label's constraints are set up in such a way that it follows the table's expansion.

**After Edit:**

After more experimentation, it looks like the timer method is the only way to make it work for moving the label (rather than expanding it) too. In that case the width constraint would be to the table view itself.

**After Second Edit:**

More experiments. I found out that the problem was calling layoutSubviews (which you shouldn't call directly) instead of layoutIfNeeded. So, you can make the label position animate without a timer. Here's the code I used to make the headers, and do the expansion on a button click:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *view = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] init];
    view.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    label.text = @"Test";
    [view.contentView addSubview:label];
    [view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[label]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"label":label}]];
    [view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    return view;
}

-(IBAction)expandTable:(id)sender {
    self.widthCon.constant = 300;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I'm not actually changing the width of the label at all, only its position. So perhaps what Ryan Poolos said is true for width changes, but for position changes, at least in this case, that's not the issue.

It's possible that using a timer to manually move the label's frame would work, but that's pretty messy. I'd like that to be a last resort - it seems to me there should be a way to indicate to the Section Header View that it should animate?

Comment: @BreadicalMD, Ok, sorry, I misunderstood your problem. But my advice to animate with constraints still stands -- if animate the table's width change using constraints, the label position should follow along properly. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: That doesn't work either :( And unfortunately, trying that stopped the table itself from animating - it's width now changes instantly rather than animating.

    `self.tableWidth.constant = 320;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.22
                          delay:0.02
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^
     {
         [menuTable layoutSubviews];
         [self.view layoutSubviews];
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
     }];`

Comment: @BreadicalMD, yeah, I just test this too, and the label didn't animate properly -- I'm still looking for the solution to that. But for me, the table view, and its header views do animate properly, so I'm not sure why yours didn't.

Comment: I can't see any way to get the Section Header Views and their Subviews to animate. I've resorted to your animation solution - which works very well. Now I just have to time it correctly with the other animations. Thanks.

Comment: @BreadicalMD, yeah, I just concluded the same thing. There is a discussion of this in one of the videos about constraints at the WWDC 2012, that talks about this problem.

Comment: @BreadicalMD, after some more experimentation, I did get it to work using animateWithDuration:animations:, using what I had in my first edit (calling layoutSubviews on self.view and self.tableView). It didn't work when I made my header views UIViews, but it did work if I made them UITableViewHeaderFooterViews. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: @BreadicalMD, actually, I found out, you only need to call layoutIfNeeded on self.view -- it turns out that using layoutSubviews was the problem, not the class of the header view. So, it actually works fine with a plain UIView as long as you call layoutIfNeeded.